# instanceof operator is not working with Class type variable

Tags: java, class, instanceof

I have a condition -

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
A a = new B();



boolean flag = a instanceof B; // returns true

public boolean isOfType(A a, Class<? extends A> type) {
    return (a instanceof type); // throws syntax error
}
```

I am very curious why the condition is throwing syntax error. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be using `type.isInstance(a)`. `instanceof` is not for objects of type `Class`, but for class names, e.g. `a instanceof String`, not `a instanceof String.class`.